# Generating an access token for a Facebook application

Tags: facebook-authentication

I have been to the [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) page and successfully generated an access token, but the token I receive doesn't give me the same permissions as the token that is automatically generated if you visit http://graph.facebook.com/ and click on the example objects.

**Here's what I'm  doing:**

I've created an app and installed it as a page tab. I can currently lookup the users who like the page tab, and get basic information about them, but I need an access token to get more information (such as the permissions that come with the token that is generated in the link above)

The access token that is generated for the examples at http://graph.facebook.com/, is that simply a test only token or can I generate one that gives the same permissions without asking the user to share their information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on what information you are looking for. Take a peek at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ for the different permissions, and figure out what you need.

If it is just an app token, the one that you got should be ok.

If not, you need to authenticate and authorize your users first. This will mean popping up an auth dialog, and asking for permissions. You can find out more about that here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

If you are doing the server side flow, make sure you are making both requests, not just stopping after the "code" - it is used to get the auth token, but offers nothing in terms of letting you do anything with it.